# alertView from appDelegate does not switch view uppon buttonIndex

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertview, appdelegate

I am trying to create an alertView from the appDelegate but I cant get it to work. The alertView will act as a disclaimer when the app launches for the first time. I cant get it to work..the introViewcontroller does not appear. what am I doing wrong? ps. i use storyboards except for the intoViewController which is a nib file.my root view controller is a "fisrtViewController" here is my code: Thank you..

```
int a;
```

and in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
    if ( a == 0) {

UIAlertView *disclaimer = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Read Before use" message:@"By using this app you agree to its terms and conditions.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\ntext heren\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No!" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes Let me In", nil];

[disclaimer show];
}


// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}

-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (buttonIndex == 1) {
  //  FirstViewController *firstView = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    a+=1;
  //  [self.viewController presentModalViewController:firstView animated:YES];
}
else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:@"You are not allowed to use this app due to the fact that you did not agree to the terms and Conditions. Please exit this app!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

if (buttonIndex ==1) {
       introViewController *intro = [[introViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"introViewController" bundle:nil];
       [self.viewController presentModalViewController:intro animated:YES];
   introViewController *intro = [[introViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"introViewController" bundle:nil];
   [self.viewController presentModalViewController:intro animated:YES];
}
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine. Are you sure the code is being executed? also, you should initialize a before your if statement (a = 0;)

Comment: yes.. the intro view controller is not presenting.. any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ahh... Now I Understand what you are trying to do.

You problem is that `self.viewController` is not set before you try to present a new modal ViewController. Also, I think your buttonIndex is of by one.

Try instead:

```
if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        introViewController *intro = [[introViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"introViewController" bundle:nil];
        _window.rootViewController = _intro;
        [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
```

Since your problem has nothing to to do with the `UIAlertView`, You might want to change the title and description of your question to make it more clear, for others struggling with a similar problem.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: well.. thanks but it does not work.just to give you a more clear image of the simulator, the firstViewController is already in background when the alertview is displayed and uppon press of the buttonIndex it does not switch either to the specified nib nor it can switch the rootViewController as the firstViewController is already the rootViewController.. thanks

Comment: OK. You need to post the full code, otherwise you keep people guessing in blind.

Comment: thats it.. i'm just saying what the output is..I'm sorry if I made you feel uncomfortable.. can you check it with team viewer? if you want to please contact me at snakeye-cy@hotmail.com so i can give you my access codes.. thanks

Comment: for your code to work you must construct self.viewController somewhere. I can't see where you do that in the code above.

Comment: introViewController *intro = [[introViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"introViewController" bundle:nil];    [self.viewController presentModalViewController:intro animated:YES]; its the last 2 lines..

Comment: yes. this is where you construct the IntroViewController. Where do you construct self.viewController?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17069/discussion-between-snksnk-and-cipramill)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this use a some NSString value write to NSUserDefaults file. when the app first time launch with the accepting the disclaimer (eg:@"accept") if user not accepting also update that NSString value accordingly.(@"notAccept").

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"key_disclaimer"] isEqualToString:@"accepted"]) {  
UIAlertView *disclaimer = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Read Before use" message:@"By using this app you agree to its terms and conditions.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\ntext heren\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No!" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes Let me In", nil];   
[disclaimer show];
[disclaimer release];  
//        make sure to release it.  
}
```

//if user accept the disclaimer.
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"accepted" forKey:@"key_disclaimer"];
//if user not accept the disclaimer,
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"notAccepted" forKey:@"key_disclaimer"];

update "key_disclaimer" accordingly. thats the best way. in your example the value of a using in the temporally. if you close and restart the app it will ask again the disclaimer.

in your code
int a;
replace it by using
int a = 0; 
it will be ok.
thanx.

Comment: thanks for the clarification but the main problem i have is that the appropriate nib file is not pushed to view and i dont know why.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If your code is exactly like you wrote above, a won't be 0.
If you don't explicitly set it to 0 at startup, it might have any value.

If you want to check if the app was opened the first time after installing, use NSUserDefaults 
e.g. (in didFinishWithOptions):

```
int startCount=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] intForKey:@"startCount"];
if (startCount==0]){
  //Is the first start, show your agreement
  //Then increase startCount so that this will not be called at next start
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:startCount++ forKey:@"startCount"];
}
```

You could also store your version number in the NSUserDefaults. This way, you could check if the user first starts a new version.

Comment: yea i dont have any problems with that as my main problem is that the specific viewcontroller (intro) is not pushed to view. please read my full description

Comment: Ah, sorry.
Have you checked self.viewcontroller is not nil?